# Eclipse LogCat getting spammed by OpenGLRenderer

Tags: android, eclipse

I am developing an android app (Phonegap) and whenever I am testing on the device that is plugged in I cannot see the error on the log because of OpenGLRenderer prepareDirty populating the log. It's very annoying, how to get rid of it?

**Device: Lenovo Tab A7**

see screenshot:
[image]

Comment: you can restrict your registers by searching by tag. Type tag:value to do it.

Comment: What is the tag to see javascript's `console.log` entries?

Comment: ok thanks, I got it using `Tag:CordovaLog`

Answer (score 12):

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>
```

or for the activity

```
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
```

After a fair amount of google research, turning off hardware acceleration was the only workaround found. Set the following in your manifest for the entire application

Comment: I think it's a device problem, and should be fixed by device options.

Answer (score 3):

to do custome log message filter

you can set custome filter in **android studio**.

and add follow **tag** and your package name

^(?!.*(OpenGLRenderer)).*$

where OpenGLRenderer can be replace with the tag that you want to ignore

like ^(?!.*(youctag1|tag2|tag3)).*$

Answer (score 2):

if you are using Android Studio, you can get rid of those annoying messages by adding a `filter configuration` with :

```
Log Tag:
^((?!(?:OpenGLRenderer|GraphicBuffer|MaliEGL)).)*$
```

and don't forget to set your package name.